# Post to facebook wall from PHP

Tags: php, facebook

Am having this little challenge posting to users facebook wall using PHP. Have already registered users and have been authorized to post to their walls using publish_stream and offline_access.

I need to retrieve their user_id i save in my database and use it to post to their wall.

This is a copy of my script.

```
$query = "select * from user_details ";
//echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    //create message with token gained before
    $post =  array(
        //'access_token' => 'TOKEN HERE',
        'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken(),
        'message' => 'Hello');

    $uid = $rows[uid];

    $res = $facebook->api($uid.'/feed', 'POST', $post);
}
```

The purpose of using `$facebook->api($uid.'/feed', 'POST', $post);` instead of 
`$facebook->api('me/feed', 'POST', $post);` is to be able to get their user_id and post to their walls.

Comment: so, what problem are you having?

Comment: what error do you get ? besides, you need to take in consideration that facebook does not allow to programmatic send post to all friend the same massage automatic - it's a spam, and it is not allowed to be done throw an application, and facebook might block your application. 
you should use to ability to

Comment: Consider sharing with us the output of `$uid` and `$res`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `mysql_query`? We're not partying like its 1999, it's 2012 so use MySQLi or - my suggestion - PDO.

You don't need to get the specific user id if you are just posting to the users wall; using `/me/feed` is fine. If you are trying to post to friends walls then that is spam, so don't do that.